# Atlaskit Modal Touch Scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, atlaskit

Does anyone know how to enable touch scroll in the Atlaskit Modal, I lost 2 days seeking for answer?

```
const NewVehicleModal = ({ isOpen, handleModal, currentStep }) => {
  return (
    <ModalTransition>
      {isOpen && (
        <Modal
          onClose={handleModal}
          height="100%"
          components={{
            Header: Header,
            Footer: Footer,
            Body: Body,
            Container: Wrapper
          }}
        >
          {items[currentStep].content()}
        </Modal>
      )}
    </ModalTransition>
```

In the header I put Progress Tracker, Body forms and footer actions, mouse scroll work perfectly but **touch scroll** in Mobile View do not work.

Comment: Same here. Similar topic: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3661